# Need extra double quotes in json < key value > in python

Tags: python, json

I am dumping < key , value > data to json file.

```
           json.dump("{}: {}".format(key,value), json_file)
           json_file.write('\n')
```

The format of resultant file is like this :

```
"key1: value1"
"key2: value2"
"key3: value3"
"key4: value4"
```

But the required file format is like this :

```
"key1": "value1"
"key2": "value2"
"key3": "value3"
"key4": "value4"
```

I tried to add extra double quotes in `dump` statement but it didn't work 
`json.dump("{}": "{}".format(key,value), json_file)`
Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't dump a formatted string, just make the dictionary and dump that.`json.dump({key: value})`

Comment: Also, what you are aiming to write is not valid JSON anyway, so it's not clear how you want this to work. My comment would at least give you valid JSON Lines but maybe that's not what you want

Comment: No. I want the given format only. It is required by another application for which I am creating this file.

Comment: The "required file format" has nothing to do with JSON…

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments you simply want a new-line separated set of key/value pairs? 
I'm not sure that's a sensible format or why you would try and use the `json` module for that.

Anyway one way to achieve what you want (assuming your key value pairs are a dict) is:

```
with open(json_file, 'w') as out_j:
    for k, v in your_dict.items():
        out_j.write('"{}": "{}"\n'.format(k, v))
```